# "not-recognized" - not-required?

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Do we really need the [not-recognized](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/not-recognized) tag? There's [unrecognized](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/unrecognized) which needs to be killed too

Comment: Why wouldn't we?

Comment: Those look like meta tags to me. They should be whacked.

Comment: @cpast Why _would_ we? I know I'm not going to add [tag:not-recognized] to my subscription list. It's a useless description of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every tag should convey useful information representative of the nature of the question.  These tags aren't very meaningful because all they say is that *something* is not recognized.  That *something* can be a lot of different things.  Therefore, these tags should be deleted.

Comment: Yeah, they're already gone, given the "status-completed" tag.